# Generic methods in conjunction with generic containers

Tags: java, generics, generic-method

I currently have a class that contain a specific Collection implementation, much like the following example:

```
public class Bag {

    Set<?> items;

    public <T> Set<T> getItems() {
        return (Set<T>) items;
    }
}
```

I now need to generalise the container, but I have troubles understanding how to obtain a similar getItems() method:

```
public abstract class AbstractBag<S extends Collection<?>> {

    S items;

    public <T> S<T> getItems(){  // <- does not compile
        return (S<T>) items;
    }
}
```

The final aim is to obtain the same original Bag, or Bag with other containers, as follow:

```
public class SetBag extends AbstractBag<Set<?>> {}
public class ListBag extends AbstractBag<List<?>> {}
```

Is it possible?
Thanks.

EDIT: I will provide more details on why (I think) this code is necessary. I have a class that need to support attributes of any type. These attributes are a collection of values of that particular type (e.g. a set of strings, a set of integers, or a set of WhateverClass). I have a map that stores this data associated to a given key. It is then possible to retrieve the data by calling the key and casting the return object correctly. For convenience, this is done through the generic method above.

Now, I need to have a second class where the collection type is different. To avoid code repetition (much more code than what is here), I would like to create an abstract class that has the collection as a generic type (like AbstractBag), and obtain the two classes with different containers (for instance one with Lists and one with Sets) as done for SetBag and ListBag.

Comment: Why do you want typed methods? Usually, the element type in the container would be parametarised.

Comment: This is an oversimplification of the actual code. I will expand the question to make more clear the reason why I need this.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    SetBag<Integer> setBag = new SetBag<>();
}

public static abstract class AbstractBag<S extends Collection<?>>
{
    S items;

    public S getItems()
    {
        return items;
    }
}

public static class SetBag<T> extends AbstractBag<Set<T>>
{
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, like in the original Bag class, the type needs to be assigned when retrieved through the getItems() method.

Comment: Dont do it even if it is possible. It doesn't make any sense and probably would cause many bugs

Comment: This is an oversimplification of the actual code. I will expand the question to make more clear the reason why I need this.